# Removing repeated commas from Pandas Dataframe Column in other words I just need the text from the column with a comma separating them

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text

I have this dataframe with the `Text` column

| Text | Cleaned Col |
| --- | --- |
| , , , Apples , , , Hard Work , , | Apples, Hard Work |
| , , , , , , , , Apples , , , , , | Apples |
| Apples , , Watermelon , , , , , , | Apples, Watermelon |
| , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , |  |

I would like to create a column such as `Cleaned Col` essentially using regex.

I looked at different patterns such as this `r'\s*,*([^(a-zA-Z)]*)'` but I am not getting the right outcome.

Comment: Could you please also let know if the fields can contain whitespaces? At first, I decided there can be none and suggested `df['Cleaned Col'] = df['Text'].str.findall(r'[^\s,]+').str.join(', ')`, but on second thought, I assumed you oversimplified your input for the question. So, can there be `, , , Red-green apples , , ,` -like values in the column? I added both solutions to my answer, but it would be nice to know your exact requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your fields are comma-delimited you can use

```py
# If the fields CANNOT contain whitespace:
df['Cleaned Col'] = df['Text'].str.findall(r'[^\s,]+').str.join(', ')

# If the fields can contain whitespace:
df['Cleaned Col'] = df['Text'].str.findall(r'[^\s,](?:[^,]*[^\s,])?').str.join(', ')
```

The regex extracts all found matches and `.str.join(', ')` joins the resulting list items into a single string. The regex ([see its demo](https://regex101.com/r/b0gdpP/3)) means:

- `[^\s,]+` - *one or more* chars other than whitespace and comma
- `[^\s,]` - a *single* char other than whitespace and comma
- `(?:[^,]*[^\s,])?` - an optional occurrence of any zero or more chars other than a comma and then a char other than whitespace and comma.

If you have your commas padded with spaces and you really want to use `Series.str.replace`, you could use

```py
df['Cleaned Col'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r'^[\s,]+|[\s,]+$|(\s)*(,)[\s,]*', r'\2\1', regex=True)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b0gdpP/2).

*Details*:

- `^[\s,]+` - one or more whitespaces or commas at the start of string
- `[\s,]+$` - one or more whitespaces or commas at the end of string
- `(\s)*(,)[\s,]*` - zero or more whitespaces (the last one matched is kept in Group 1, `\1`), then a comma (captured into Group 2, `\2`) and then zero or more whitespace or comma chars.

The replacement is Group 2 + Group 1 values.

Comment: Thank you so much for a thorough explanation. This solution works aswell. Learned a lot of new things thanks to your detailed answer!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for get words and join by comma:

```
df['Cleaned Col'] = df['Text'].str.findall('\w+').str.join(', ')
print (df)
                                      Text         Cleaned Col
0      , , , Apples , , , Bananas , , ,        Apples, Bananas
1    , , , , , , , , Apples , , , , ,                   Apples
2        Apples , , Watermelon , , , , , ,  Apples, Watermelon
3  , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked and it's so simple!

Comment: @codemunchkin - Super! So not possible words like `red apple`, it means with spaces?

Comment: Sorry I spoke too soon for instances like red apple your solution doesn't work it splits it like this red, apple but I want it like red apple

Comment: @codemunchkin - So then working only `Wiktor Stribiżew` solution.

Comment: Jezrael yes Wiktor Stribizew 's solution worked.

Answer (score 4):

You could try replacing the commas with spaces, then clearing out the left and right spaces and replacing the middle spaces with a comma:

```
df['Cleaned Col'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',', ' ').lstrip().rstrip().replace(' ', ', ')
```